# Angular router '**' wildcard as a catch-all with child routes? Using latest 2.4.0 and Router 3.4.1

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've been experimenting with dozens of configurations trying to get this to work but cannot figure this out.

Given url as follows:

- https://domain.com                   Dashboard
- https://domain.com/profile           Profile
- https://domain.com/anything         ...catch all with children.

  - https://domain.com/anything/edit
- https://domain.com/otherthing

  - https://domain.com/otherthing/edit

`anything` and `otherthing` can literally be anything.

A route configuration I hoped would work but ends up taking over the defined routes where https://domain.com/profile would trigger the catchall ('**'), which seems very odd since to my understanding, the catchall should only fire or catch routes that are not defined above it:

Where `app.module` has this:

```js
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module'
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: 'app/profile/profile.module'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    loadChildren: 'app/anything/anything.module'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent]
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Where `anything.module` has this:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',  // hoping to pick up the wildcard as param this way
    component: AnyComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'edit',
        component: EditComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    AnyComponent,
    EditComponent
  ]
})
export default class AnythingModule {}
```

Is there anyway to make the above use case work with the Angular Router 3.4.1?

Comment: How do the routes for `AppModule` look like?

Comment: It's the first set of routes...export const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module'
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: 'app/profile/profile.module'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    loadChildren: 'app/anything/anything.module'
  }
];

Comment: Did you get the lazy module routes to work with the wildcard? Something similar happens to me. You can see it in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279174/angular-7-router-wildcard-with-lazy-load-module-and-child-routes-not-workin

Answer (score 2):

This was asked a year ago. However I was using Angular 5.1.2 and found myself with the same problem

This was a bug with the router solved on issue #[18139](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/18139), I updated to 5.2.1 on my package.json to get the fix

```
"@angular/core": "^5.2.1",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.1",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.1",
```

etc...

Comment: Does lazy load child routes work with ** catchall wildcard? Could you take a look on this thread and check if it is possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279174/angular-7-router-wildcard-with-lazy-load-module-and-child-routes-not-workin Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If `ProfileModule` doesn't have a `path: ''` route, then there is no route to match and the router continues to match remaining routes.

Comment: Even if I use a component with no child paths for `profile` like this: {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent }, still encounters same issue?

Comment: That's quite unlikely. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: I'll try to create one tomorrow, thx for help, been banging head on this for awhile.

Comment: Ok here's the plunkr demonstrating the catch all not working as described in original post: https://plnkr.co/edit/QfXx5KJGfhMskIldA0AA?p=preview  Am I missing something? I would expect the `AnythingComponent` to show when clicking on the 'whatever' link. Is there anyway to get this working? thank you.

Comment: In plunker you need to enable `HashLocationStrategy`. https://plnkr.co/edit/FpXpBH0sPSCoDixKyisB?p=preview I can't reproduce the problem. Can you please check?

Comment: Thanks, just tried it - looks like you were able to add `HashLocationStrategy`, but yeah still doesn't work with that. Open console, you should see `created [component name]` when clicking each route which you will see for dashboard and profile but nothing for `AnythingComponent` when clicking on the `whatever` link. Do you see that?

Comment: Shoot n/p, thank you so much for taking a look. I'll keep trying things. Would really love to know if anyone knows how to make this use case work.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html has a link to a running Plunker in the 2nd paragraph. I couldn't find what they do differently but that Plunker seems to run fine. (https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/eplnkr.html)

Comment: I ended up adding a bug report about this as the bug was verified here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13848 ... looks like this PR will solve it: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13851