# Angular 7 router '**' wildcard with lazy load module and child routes not working?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, wildcard, angular-router

I'm trying to create a default route using the wildcard '**' from Angular's router. That default route will load a lazy module and then it will have to solve its own routes. The problem is that when I have the following configuration it does not resolve as expected:

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: 'DashboardComponent'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent]
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: MainComponent
  }
  {
    path: 'hello',  // hoping to pick up the wildcard and resolve the route
    component: HelloComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    AnyComponent,
    EditComponent
  ]
})
export default class LazyModule {}
```

For example. With mydomain.com/hello it does not show me the HelloComponent, it shows me the MainComponent.

Is there something wrong with my configuration or should it not work like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `mydomain.com/hello/hello`. My guess is that it resolves the wildcard for the first path value but then considers the lazy module routing scheme for the next level of the path and since `/hello`'s second part is nothing then it resolves to the first route. I have never seen lazy-loading on the wildcard route before, but I would assume you must use some type of secondary path part to resolve further in that sub-module

Comment: @TimKlein Thanks for your help. I just tried what you told me since it makes all the sense in the world but it still does not work. It seems that it takes /hello/hello as the root path and always shows the LazyComponent. 
Could you do a test if it's not too much trouble? Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to redirect to an actual route. There are a few topics related to this, [here is one](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13848#issuecomment-345839813). Also per [Angular's examples](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules), you might have to export your RouterModule from LazyModule.

Answer (score 0):

The lazy modules require two routing configuration. The first one which is in the appModule tells the angular when to load the module. The second one which is in the lazy feature module, tells the angular when to display a specific component.

In your case, change the path of the appModule routing to be `hello`. This tells the angular to download the lazy module when sees the `hello` url.
As of the second configuration, leave it empty. This tells angular to load the component when it sees an empty string following the `hello` url

**AppModule**

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: 'DashboardComponent'
  },
  {
    path: 'helllo', <-- change this
    loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
  }
];
```

**LazyModule**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: LazyComponent // I do not know what this is. The components are not lazy. Modules are
  }
  {
    path: '',  <-- change this
    component: HelloComponent
  }
];
```

I saw in your code that you have a **LazyComponent**. I do not know what you are trying to achieve with this but the components are not lazy. Modules are.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to solve the same scenario as in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276372/angular-router-wildcard-as-a-catch-all-with-child-routes-using-latest-2-4. I know how the lazy modules work, but I'm trying to use the '**' wildcard to see if it worked in this scenario. 
The name LazyComponent is just a name I gave to that component. This thread contains all the info: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13848